# How to verify email before creating user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to send a verification email to a user who just registered.

His account is not created unless he verifies his email address.

---

**MY CODE:**

```
 var userAuth = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        userAuth.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {

            req.flash('success_msg', 'Please verify your email address. You have 60 seconds');

            setTimeout(function(){ 

                if(userAuth.emailVerified) {
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(userData => { 

                        var user = {
                            email: email,
                            username: username,
                        }

                        firebase.database().ref('users/'+userData.uid.toString()).set(user);

                        req.flash('success_msg', 'You have registered and logged in.');
                        res.redirect('...');

                    }).catch(error => {
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        req.flash('error_msg', 'Registration Failed. ' + error.message);
                        res.redirect('/users/register');
                        console.log("Error creating user: ", error);
                    });  
                } else {
                    req.flash('error_msg', 'Registration Failed.');
                    res.redirect('/users/register');
                }

            }, 60000); 

        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

`userAuth` is of course `null` since the user hasn't been created yet. This means my code crashes.

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I achieve what I am looking for ?

Or is there a better way ?

---

**REFERENCE**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: In order to be able to process the confirmation, you have to store something related to the pending user.  You either create a user object and put it in a "pending" state that your code won't let be used for anything other than a confirmation or you create a separate type of object (a pending confirmation object) and that's all that exists until the confirmation happens.  You do not want your existing request handler to "wait" until the confirmation happens.

Comment: And, your current scheme only gives your user 60 seconds to do the confirmation.  Some email systems/clients won't even offer the email to the end user in that much time.  You need a design where the confirmation can be done any time in the next few seconds or up to tens of minutes from now.  The email confirmation link can take the end user to the next step in the sign up process.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand your reasoning. But if I create a pending object, that means that anyone can start spamming my database with useless data. I have planned 10 min timers and IP limits, but I know those can be bypassed by a skilled enough hacker. I would like an approach where NO DATA gets written at all unless confirmed from a valid email address. That way, the attack becomes much harder to perform. Is there a way to do that or am I just dreaming of a solution that does not exist ?

Comment: Well, your current scheme allows attackers to load up your server with requests just waiting for something to happen which will probably either exhaust your memory or sockets.  It's actually much better to have a tiny object stored in the database that you can clean out every few hours or so if they aren't confirmed.  And, it's likely that some well intentioned users can't even do the confirmation in 60 seconds like you have coded so you'll just frustrate some of the legit users.

Comment: You're pursuing a bad design in order to protect yourself from something that isn't very much of a threat in the first place and something that you can protect yourself from in other ways that cause far less risk to your design.

Comment: @jfriend00 Your suggested approach is already much better than the approach I currently have in my code, I agree. But is there really no way to not store any data at all until verification ? Storing pending data is (in essence) rather redundant I find. If there is no better way, I will use that, but I just want to make sure :)

Comment: You HAVE to store something.  When a confirmation link comes in, you have to have something to compare it to that you've previously stored.  Otherwise, people could just make up confirmation links on their own and you'd happily process them.  Storing something you created at the time of the original request is how you authenticate the confirmation link when that request arrives at your server and it's how you associate it with the right user object.  I don't understand what the objection is to storing a small (probably under 100 bytes) account pending object in your database?

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it ! That makes perfect sense. Could you please write an answer to the question so I can accept it rather than deleting my question :D ?

Comment: I put the comments into an answer as you requested.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting my collection of comments into an answer since it seems to have answered your question for you.

In order to be able to process the confirmation request when it comes in, you have to store something related to the pending user. You either create a user object and put it in a "pending" state that your code won't let be used for anything other than a confirmation or you create a separate type of object (a pending confirmation object) and that's all that exists until the confirmation happens. You do not want your existing request handler to "wait" until the confirmation happens.

Your current scheme allows attackers to load up your server with requests just waiting for something to happen which will probably either exhaust your memory or sockets. It's actually much better to have a tiny object stored in the database that you can clean out every few hours or so if they aren't confirmed. And, it's likely that some well intentioned users can't even do the confirmation in 60 seconds like you have coded so you'll just frustrate some of the legit users.

You HAVE to store something. When a confirmation link comes in, you have to have something to compare it to that you've previously stored. Otherwise, people could just make up confirmation links on their own and you'd happily process them. Storing something you created at the time of the original request is how you authenticate the confirmation link when that request arrives at your server and it's how you associate it with the right user object. I don't understand what the objection is to storing a small (probably under 100 bytes) account pending object in your database?

Comment: You are a legend ! Thank you :) People like you make SO great !